# Summation of field values using keyup event

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate the summation of each column using jquery.
html:

```
<table id="tab"width="300px" border="1" >
<tbody><tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Cheese</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
         <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Eggs</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
         <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Milk</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
         <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="summation">

    <td colspan="2"align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td><input class="sum" type="text" name="txt"></td>
        <td><input class="sum" type="text" name="txt"></td>
</tr>
     </tbody></table>
```

Here I want to adding values(using keyup function) of each column and shows in last row.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tgbxy31/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val()` for input instead of `.html()` and try the below code

```
var sum = 0;
$("#tab input").keyup(function(){
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tgbxy31/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

to

```
$("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Because if we want to populate input, jquery has `val()` not `html()`.
`html()` is for span.

And add one more condition in your if() that is `&& this.id!="sum"`,
So that it won't take the sum value in calculation.
Okay

Answer (score 1):

Write `.val()` instead of `.html()` and do some minor changes in the code as:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $("#tab").find("input").each(function(){
                          $(this).keyup(function(){
                              //alert("here")
                              calculateSum();
                          });
                      });
                  });
function calculateSum()
{
    var sum=0;
    $("#tab tr").not("tr:last").each(function(){
      $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function()  {
        if(!isNaN(this.value)&&this.value.length!=0)
        {
          sum+=parseInt(this.value);
        }
      });      
    });  
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5tgbxy31/5/)