# How to get 2 textboxes input value result into the 3rd textbox without hit submit button on the same page in PHP+MySQL by using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am new in coding and don't know about Javascript and Jquery. But I am good in PHP code. Here is my code for the HTML form and PHP code as well,

Please help me how I can get the result calculation on annual+discount in net amount text box without the hit on the submit button. If any script will help then please help me here with Jquery or javascript which can resolve this task.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
    border: 2px solid #00701c;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.txt-box {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.title-1 input {
    background-color: #00701c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 10.5%;
}
.title-2 input {
    background-color: #0011cc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 10.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Passing values to text box without hit submit button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div class="txt-box">
  <form method="post">
   <div class="title">Annual Charges</div><div><input type="text" name="charges" /></div>
   <div class="title">Discount</div><div><input type="text" name="discount" /></div>
   <div class="title">Net Amount</div><div><input type="text" name="netamount" /></div>
   <div class="title"></div><div class="title-1"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit" /></div>
   <div class="title"></div><div class="title-2"><input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Reset" /></div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need result without click on submit button in the net amount text field by using any script like javascript or Jquery in PHP and then I will submit the values to the database.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use keyup method of jquery

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free programming service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summation of field values using keyup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046242/summation-of-field-values-using-keyup-event)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Passing values to text box without hit submit button</title>
    <script>
    function update_net_amount(){
        var netamount = $('#charges').val() - $('#discount').val();
        $('#netamount').val( netamount );

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="txt-box">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="title">Annual Charges</div><div><input id="charges" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount();" type="text" name="charges" /></div>
                <div class="title">Discount</div><div><input id="discount" onchange="javascript:update_net_amount();"  type="text" name="discount" /></div>
                <div class="title">Net Amount</div><div><input id="netamount" type="text" name="netamount" disabled /></div>
                <div class="title"></div><div class="title-1"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit" /></div>
                <div class="title"></div><div class="title-2"><input type="reset" name="cancel" value="Reset" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Will you help that how we can subtract discount in percentage value and get the result in net amount textbox?

Comment: change the calculation in function as per below: var netamount = $('#charges').val() * ( $('#discount').val() / 100) ;

Comment: Please, consider flagging low-quality questions instead of answering them.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Low quality question? Have you ever heard of learning process? some people are new to things and go around asking questions

Comment: @Mason.Chase You are new to this website just as a question author. If low-quality attempts at learning were fine for this platform, it'd sink under the weight of millions of such questions. This website is for _professional_ programmers. It's stated right in the title.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph define "Professional Programmer" and besides the home page says: "Stack Overflow is a community of 7.3 million programmers, just like you, helping each other.  Join them; it only takes a minute"

Comment: @Mason.Chase Then the policy has changed. Welcome to the website of low-quality questions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

This is working perfectly for me hope its work for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <title>Passing values to text box without hit submit button</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="container">
<div class="txt-box">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="title">Annual Charges</div><div><input type="text" ` 
       name="charges"  class="annualCharge"/></div>
        <div class="title">Discount</div><div><input type="text"                   
       name="discount" class="discount" /></div>
        <div class="title">Net Amount</div><div><input type="text" 
       name="netamount" class="netamount" /></div>
        <div class="title"></div><div class="title-1"><input type="submit" 
      name="add" value="Submit" /></div>
        <div class="title"></div><div class="title-2"><input type="reset" 
      name="cancel" value="Reset" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">


    $('.annualCharge,.discount').on("keyup",function(){


        var annualCharge=parseInt($('.annualCharge').val());
        var discount=parseInt($('.discount').val());
        var netamount=annualCharge-discount;
        console.log(netamount);

        if(!isNaN(netamount))
        {
            $('.netamount').val(netamount);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.netamount').val("");
        }



});



    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: it is advised to write script tag within the <header> section

Comment: Sorry mate I have to follow your code and adjust script into header section but not works. The result will not be passed to net amount text box. @Saurabh Gupta

Comment: have you included jquery library? Check out for the jquery library properly

Comment: yes, I have added the library and it is not working, so please can you check from your side.

Comment: I have also done some changes in your HTML code please check out that too.I have actually added some classes to your input boxes

Comment: do one thing copy whole of my code and just add jquery library and check

Comment: @Mason.Chase It was never advised to have scripts in `<head>`, because that slows down the page load process. You're just making an advice reverse to common good practices.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph, why you give the negative mark to my question. Please revert it.
if you have the better solution then please provide don't find the remedy here.

Thanks.

Comment: @KamalHasija Because your question shows lack of basic knowledge, including the knowledge that Google exists. It violates half of the rules of this website like having MCVE, respecting others' time and checking if the question is duplicate. And as a cherry on top of the pie you reverted back the edit that removed most of those mistakes. If I could downvote twice, I would do it.

Comment: If someone is the beginner in coding then from where he can learn the exact things.
I think no one is perfect in technology and if you then go ahead, sir.
sorry for this question, I never asked any question here again in the future. You are a true man, @polkovnikov.ph

Comment: @KamalHasija Start with asking Google instead of StackOverflow. It takes less time both for you and other people. Consider reading the [tutorial on JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics), [jQuery manual](https://api.jquery.com/) to improve your skill instead of relying on low-quality answers like you've got for this question. Read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of website you're using.